# jQuery mouseover event triggers multiple times when moving mouse quicker

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using jquery mouseover event to fetch some data using ajax in wordpress, ajax is working fine, but my issue is When we move the mouse over the element faster event triggers multiple actions, ie if i give an alert on mouse over if I move repeatedly over the element I will get multiple alerts, I dont want this, I have tried unbind, but not working properly. here is the

```
<ul class="tab-content">
<li><div class="place-holder"></div></li>
<li><div class="place-holder"></div></li>
<li><div class="place-holder"></div></li>
<li><div class="place-holder"></div></li>
</ul>


$(document).on('mouseover', '.place-holder' , function(e){
alert ('hallo');
}
```

Comment: So the `mouseover` should only work once?

Comment: since all your div has the same class.. it will trigger multiple times when you hover on each of them

Comment: @krishna - thats ok, but the issu is if you move the mouse faster over a div continuously it will be triggerd multiple times, i dont want to happen this, i am looking for some thing like queue:false--- something like this. Actually  iwant to trigger an ajax request on mouse enter.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to delay the action with a timer. Just like the :

```
var timer;
$(document).on('mouseover', '.place-holder' , function(e){
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        alert('Hallo');
    }, 200)
})
```

This way, your event will trigger 0.2 sec after the mouse over and will trigger only once if you move fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.place-holder').mouseenter(function(){
      alert('hello');
   })
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ - mouseenter jquery reference

Answer (score 0):

Actually issue was related to Ajax Call, when I Fire an event it triggers multiple times before the ajax result comes. so what i did is used a boolean tag like this

```
 if (window.isRunning) return;
 window.isRunning = true;
```

and in ajax

```
complete : function () {
                            window.isRunning = false;
                    }
```

so now it will not fire multiple times, I got this from Stack itself, thanks a ton